# How to change JDK version in Android Studio

Tags: flutter

I get the following error when i try to run my application:

```
"Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Get java version from JAVA_HOME: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home
The photo_manager java version is 17
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/photo_manager-2.8.1/lib/src/internal/image_provider.dart:71:5: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
    DecoderCallback decode, // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/photo_manager-2.8.1/lib/src/internal/image_provider.dart:96:5: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
    DecoderCallback decode, // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/photo_manager-2.8.1/lib/src/internal/image_provider.dart:71:5: Error: 'DecoderCallback' isn't a type.
    DecoderCallback decode, // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/photo_manager-2.8.1/lib/src/internal/image_provider.dart:96:5: Error: 'DecoderCallback' isn't a type.
    DecoderCallback decode, // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Upon some investigation, I found that the wechat_assets_picker package causes the error.

To resolve it, I tried to switch to Java JDK 17, but no matter how much I go through android studio to change the JDK version, I found no way of doing so. Please note that photo_manager is not installed by me but the wechat_assets_picker package uses it as a dependency. Also, please note that I upgraded the wechat_assets_picker package to the latest version.

The version of Android Studio I am currently using is Giraffe 2022.3.1

Any help on this is certainly appreciated!